# java syncronized: why instructions monitorenter and monitorexit does not appear in pairs in my example?

Tags: java, synchronization

I'm trying to find out how keyword **syncronized** works internally in java. So I wrote a very simple example and used ***javap*** to see the byte code.

***SyncTest.java***

```
public class SyncTest {

   public void sort(int[] array) {
       synchronized(this) {
       }
   }
}
```

***do javac and javap***

```
F:\>javac SyncTest.java

F:\>javap -c SyncTest.class
Compiled from "SyncTest.java"
public class SyncTest {
  public SyncTest();
  Code:
    0: aload_0
    1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
    4: return

public void sort(int[]);
Code:
   0: aload_0
   1: dup
   2: astore_2
   3: monitorenter
   4: aload_2
   5: monitorexit
   6: goto          14
   9: astore_3
  10: aload_2
  11: monitorexit
  12: aload_3
  13: athrow
  14: return
 Exception table:
   from    to  target type
       4     6     9   any
       9    12     9   any
}
```

[image]

From the above byte code segment, I found that syncronized is working in java by using ***monitorenter*** and ***monitorexit***. However, ***I don't know why there is only 1 monitorenter but 2 monitorexit, they're not in pairs***.

Comment: Did you trace the assembly code? You have a jump `goto` in your bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one way to enter a synchronized block: by the sequential execution path that leads into the synchronized block. That's why you see one `monitorenter` instruction.

There are however two execution paths that leave the synchronized block: either by the sequential execution path at the end of the synchronized block or (if an exception is thrown) to the exception handler somewhere. Therefore you have two `monitorexit` instructions: one for the sequential path (at offset 5) and another for the exception path (at offset 11).